# Scrapy : selecting table row using 'role'

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]

I'm trying to select a table row that looks like (also screenshot):

```
<tr data-uid="65724478-5102-4fa3-8de1-17b54dd7909c" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><input id="tesT1" name="tesT1" onchange="SelectedYearDetailck({id:'R12684_2016',TaxDue:231.33,TaxYr:2016,AgEntityID:072000})" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"><input name="tesT1" type="hidden" value="false"><label for="tesT1" class="cklabel"></label><input type="hidden" id="ck_2016" value="ck_R12684"><div id="grid-wait_R12684" style="display:none;" class="grid-wait"><img src="../Content/Images/25(1).GIF"></div></td><td role="gridcell">2016</td><td style="text-align:right;" role="gridcell">$231.33</td><td style="text-align:right;" role="gridcell">$327.58</td></tr>
```

I've tried:

```
response.selector.xpath("//tr[contains(@role,'row')]")
Out[2]: []
response.selector.xpath("//tr[(@role='row')]")
Out[3]: []
```

How can I select this row using its role attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> HTML = '''\
... <tr data-uid="65724478-5102-4fa3-8de1-17b54dd7909c" role="row">
...     <td role="gridcell">...</td>
...     <td role="gridcell">2016</td>
... </tr>'''
>>> selector = Selector(text=HTML)
>>> selector.xpath('.//tr[@role="row"]').extract()
['<tr data-uid="65724478-5102-4fa3-8de1-17b54dd7909c" role="row">\n\t<td role="gridcell">...</td>\n\t<td role="gridcell">2016</td>\n</tr>']
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, I ended up using the open_in_browser(response) function and realized that 'role' was NOT in the html, although I was seeing that as an attribute in chrome dev tools.Thank you for looking at this though.

Comment: Been there, got the T-shirt.